# how can i fix this error in visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly

> 'file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports
>   for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI'

[image]

Comment: _how can i fix this error_ is not a suitable question topic. Please have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: First, try to scroll down the error text to see the full path to the missing file.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your .config file (usually app.config).

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
</startup>
```